# claims are not sent back to application using IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am having a pretty annoying problem with the Identity Server 4 running in a asp net core 2.0. some of my claims (not all) wouldn't get sent back to my app when I deploy it to production (with SSL).

It is completely fine when I run it locally. I use ProfileService by implementing IProfileService for adding those extra claims.
any ideas where to start ?

Comment: Perhaps you are missing something in your configuration. Check the IdentityClaims table for missing claim types.

Comment: What does the API accept, and what have you configured the IdentityServer to send as part of configuration setup? Can you show the code for the client setup?

Answer (score 0):

You should start from the Identity Server logs. Check both logs - your local and the production one. Check which scopes you are requested, when authenticating, and which claims are issued.

The enabled logging in IDS is essential. It helps a lot and gives a lot information. Make sure you also set the logging level to a level that gives you enough information.